# python wordnetlemmatizer: not a zip file

Tags: file, zip, lemmatization

I try the following for lemmatization:

```
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
wnl.lemmatize("dogs")
```

and keep getting "BadZipFile: File is not a zip file" error. I am unable to find anything on it in the context of lemmatization. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2):

you will get rid of it after downloading wordnet &  wordnet_ic

Answer (score 0):

python -m    nltk.downloader all

you need to download the zip-file

Comment: zip-file  wordnet

Answer (score 0):

> the `zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file` issue is due to an
> incomplete installation of nltk. so uninstall previous versions and
> follow these instructions.

First,close your IDE, then **run** your **command prompt** or anaconda prompt as an **administrator**

now, run the following commands:

```
pip install numpy
pip install nltk
```

after installing nltk,
type `python` on your command line to enter python mode

after opening python, let's import the nltk library

```
import nltk
```

now that you have imported it on your command prompt
run the following

```
nltk.download("wordnet")
nltk.download("omw-1.4")
```

now the `zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file` issue should be solved.